# I'm trying to use a CONZIR CO2 sensor to find CO2 concentration

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

Hey I’m a beginner Arduino user trying to use a CO2/Humidity/Temperature sensor to read in the atmospheric conditions near the sensor and then control a heating pad and solenoid valve to adjust the conditions to what I need. I am having a lot of trouble simply getting realistic values that are usable. It would be awesome if someone could point me in the right direction. I am trying to use sample code provided to me by CO2 meter and am not having any luck having the conditions update in the serial monitor. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code I am trying to use and linked below is the manual. After figuring out how to simply read the CO2 values, I would like to expand it to temperature and humidity.

(http://co2meters.com/Documentation/Manuals/Manual_GC_0024_0025_0026_Revised8.pdf)

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(12, 13); // RX, TX pins on Ardunio

int co2 =0;
double multiplier = 1;// 1 for 2% =20000 PPM, 10 for 20% = 200,000 PPM
uint8_t buffer[25];
uint8_t ind =0;
uint8_t index =0;

int fill_buffer();  // function prototypes here
int format_output();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("\n\n");
  Serial.println("             AN128 Ardunio to Cozir CO2 Sensor - Demonstration code 11/29/2017\n\n"); 
  mySerial.begin(9600); // Start serial communications with sensor

  // mySerial.println("G");

  pinMode(4, OUTPUT); //heating pad pin
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); //heating pad pin 
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT); //solenoid valve pin 
  digitalWrite(4, LOW); //change between HIGH or LOW value to make the valve/heating pads turn on/off
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(5, LOW);

  //mySerial.println("K 0");  // Set Command mode
  // mySerial.println("M 6"); // send Mode for Z and z outputs
  // "Z xxxxx z xxxxx" (CO2 filtered and unfiltered)
  //delay(20);

  mySerial.println("K 1");  // set streaming mode

}

void loop() {

  // Serial.println(" Hello World ");
  fill_buffer();  // function call that reads CO2 sensor and fills buffer

   Serial.print("Buffer contains: ");
  for(int j=0; j<ind; j++)Serial.print(buffer[j],HEX);
  index = 0;
  format_output();
   Serial.print(" Raw PPM        ");

   index = 8;  // In ASCII buffer, filtered value is offset from raw by 8 bytes
   format_output();
   Serial.println(" Filtered PPM\n\n");
}

int fill_buffer(void){


// Fill buffer with sensor ascii data
ind = 0;
while(buffer[ind-1] != 0x0A){  // Read sensor and fill buffer up to 0XA = CR
  if(mySerial.available()){
    buffer[ind] = mySerial.read();
    ind++;
     // Serial.println("Fill loop");
    } 
     //Serial.println("Fill loop");
  }
  // buffer() now filled with sensor ascii data
  // ind contains the number of characters loaded into buffer up to 0xA =  CR
  ind = ind -2; // decrement buffer to exactly match last numerical character
  }

 int format_output(void){ // read buffer, extract 6 ASCII chars, convert to PPM and print
   co2 = buffer[15-index]-0x30;
  co2 = co2+((buffer[14-index]-0x30)*10);
  co2 +=(buffer[13-index]-0x30)*100;
  co2 +=(buffer[12-index]-0x30)*1000;
  co2 +=(buffer[11-index]-0x30)*10000;
  Serial.print("\n CO2 = ");
  Serial.print(co2*multiplier,0);
// Serial.print(" PPM,");
//    Serial.print("\n");
   delay(200);
 }
```

Comment: what does this mean? ... `trouble simply getting realistic values`

Comment: So the value I am getting is -9600 ppm (a negative CO2 value),  and after receiving one CO2 reading it won't continue to loop and give me more readings. I was under the impression that it would continue to get buffer readings and thus be able to update and give me new readings